# Facebook MPA ad with 10 products

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I created an MPA ad on Facebook with 10 products. The ad creation was successful and I received ad-creative id in the response (reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/carousel-ads/v2.4). I also checked the ad-creative using api call and it has all the 10 products. But on Facebook UI, I can only see 5 products in the MPA ad. Why does Facebook showing only 5 products in the MPA ad even though the ad creative has 10 products in it ??

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to show 10 - the number shown varies and is automatically optimized so the products most likely to be clicked are shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the field description for `child_attachments` we specify that only 5 will be shown:

> Use to specify multiple links in the post. Minimum 2 and maximum of 5
>   objects. If you set multi_share_optimized to true, you can upload a
>   maximum of 10 objects but Facebook will display the top 5.

When using `multi_share_optimized`, the most optimal products will be shown.

See:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#pubfields